# how to build a regular expression that will match until a certain word ?

Tags: regex

I have the following text :

```
i like kittens dfhgfhfgjhgjgh and dogs
```

and i would like the regular expression to match to :

```
kittens dfhgfhfgjhgjgh and
```

there can be many words until the word dog, so i want to use a regular expression that looks something like this :

```
string myRegex = kittens[^(dogs)]  // match from kittens until you get to the word dogs
```

But i can't find any way to do it, he stops the matching when he hit's the letter d.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want a regex more like this:

```
kittens.*?(?=dogs)
```

The `.*?` matches 0 or more characters in a non-greedy fashion, and `(?=dogs)` indicates that your match should be followed by the word `dogs`.

Or if you want to make sure that the characters `dogs` comprise a word in and of themselves (and are not part of a compound word, for example), consider the following pattern (as Sam points out below):

```
kittens.*?(?=\bdogs\b)
```

The `\b` indicates a word boundary.

Your question suggests that there will always be a `dogs`. But if not, consider using the following regex (which will find matches that follow kittens but that do not contain dogs), as Justin Wood points out:

```
kittens.*?(?=\bdogs\b|$)
```

The `$` indicates the end of a string.

The output in all cases, then, will be this:

```
kittens dfhgfhfgjhgjgh and
```

Comment: I don't know if this is an issue, but this will not match anything if the word `dogs` does not appear in the string. Use `kittens.*?(?=dogs|$)` to match until end of line or `dogs`.

Comment: Replace `dogs` with `\bdogs\b` which will use some logic for checking [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) around "dog".

Comment: @Sam Also a good point. I edited the question above in light of your comment. Thanks.

Comment: @Justin Wood I also added a variation based on the option you mention. Thanks.

Comment: @Jonny 5 Thanks, Jonny, for the congrats and for pushing me  over the hump! :-)